# C# SimpleCalculator

Tags: c#, computer-science

I am trying to write a code for a `SIMPLE Calculator` and I am getting some errors:

following is the errors:

**Error 1   The name 'Valid' does not exist in the current context

Error 2 The name 'Subtract'/add/multiply, divide does not exist in the current context**

Please see what is wring with the code and suggest what i am doing wrong.

```
 int input = 0;
 double num1 = 0;
 double num2 = 0;
 string inputN1 = "";
 string inputN2 = "";
 bool validnum1 = true;
 bool validnum2 = true;

 do{
     Console.WriteLine("Simple Calculator\n\t 1) Add\n\t 2) Subtract\n\t 3) 
     Multiply\n\t 4) Divide\n\t 5) Quit\n\t ", input);
     Console.Write("Enter your Selection: ");
     input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

     if (input ==5)
     {
        Console.WriteLine();
     }
     else if (input >5)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection.\t Please Try Again");
     }
     else
     {
        Console.Write("Enter Number 1: ");
        inputN1 = Console.ReadLine();
        validnum1 = Valid(inputN1);
        Console.Write("Enter Number 2: ");
        validnum2 = Valid(inputN2);

        if (validnum1 == true && validnum2 == true)
        {
              num1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputN1);
              num2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputN2);
        }
        else 
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number Entered");
             Console.ReadKey();
             break;
         }

         switch (input)
         {
            case 1:
                   Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", Add(num1, num2));
                   break;
            case 2:
                   Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", Subtract(num1, num2));
                   break;
            case 3:
                   Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", Multiply(num1, num2));
                   break;
            case 4:
                   if (num2 == 0)
                   {
                      Console.WriteLine("Cant Divide by Zero/\t Please try Again");
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", Divide(num1, num2));
                   }
                   break;
           }
           Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
           Console.ReadKey();
           Console.Clear();
       }

   }while (input != 5 && input <5);

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key....");
      Console.ReadKey();

 }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Those aren't the operators you are looking for. You want `num1 + num2` and `num1 - num2` etc etc

Comment: Did you define the functions that you are using?

Comment: Tour source code is not complete. There are no such methods as 'Valid' or 'Add'. You have to create them.

Comment: Where did you define the Valid,Add,Subtract,Multiply and Divide methods?

Comment: So the reason for your compiler errors is that under the spec for C#, you are calling a method called `Add` that is in your class `Main`. I suspect you were looking for a library call that adds two doubles together. However, since C# is a sane language, it uses namespaces. In order to call any method (except locally defined ones) you must give the full namespace (or use the `using` directive ).

Comment: The exceptions he is getting don't specify that he is using non-static methods to Add, Subtract, Divide or Multiply. The exception or compiler error is indicating that "The name 'Valid' does not exist in the current context" which imply that he is considering Valid as built in method and trying to validate a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All there is no such thing in C# as Valid, Subtract, Add and Multiply. To check whether a given string is valid `double` use `double.TryParse()`. For Arithmetic operations use +,-,*,/ for Add, Subtract, Multiply and Divide respectively. Instead try to use this code it will work. If you are using Methods then access them through Class specifier like this `Your_Class.Add()` because to access Non-Static Methods from Static class you need class instance containing the non-static method.

```
int input = 0;
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        string inputN1 = "";
        string inputN2 = "";
        bool validnum1 = true;
        bool validnum2 = true;

        do{
            Console.WriteLine("Simple Calculator\n\t 1) Add\n\t 2) Subtract\n\t 3) Multiply\n\t 4) Divide\n\t 5) Quit\n\t ", input);
            Console.Write("Enter your Selection: ");
            input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (input ==5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else if (input >5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection.\t Please Try Again");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Number 1: ");
                inputN1 = Console.ReadLine();
                validnum1 = double.TryParse(inputN1,out num1);
                Console.Write("Enter Number 2: ");
                inputN2 = Console.ReadLine();
                validnum2 = double.TryParse(inputN2,out num2);

                if (validnum1 != true || validnum2 != true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number Entered");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                   // num1 = Convert.ToDouble(inputN1);
                   // num2 = Convert.ToDouble(inputN2);
                }

                //else  else will not be required as double.tryparse is succeeded then value will automatically assigned to respective numbers.
                //{

                //}

                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", num1+num2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", num1-num2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", num1*num2);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (num2 == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Cant Divide by Zero/\t Please try Again");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\tResults: {0}", num1/num2);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
            }


        }while (input != 5 && input <5);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key....");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: It works but it doesnt let me enter the Second number to do the calculation. It just gives an answer after entering the First number

Comment: this line was missing in your code  inputN2 = Console.ReadLine();